# How can I duplicate a mac user account including username and password?

Tags: mac, user-accounts, osx-mavericks, user, duplicate

I have an account on my friends mac that I would like to move to my mac, so is there any way to duplicate everything in that account, including username **and password**? By the way, I am using OS X Mavericks and my friend is running on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Mac has their own Migration Assistant that can migrate your username and password (and some software). Have you tried that before? Info from apple here: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5872

Answer (score 0):

You can create the core UID with this info, then use `cp`, `scp` or a 3rd party utility to move the data.

### Create a User Account from Terminal

Use the dscl command. This example would create the user "luser", like so:

```
dscl . -create /Users/luser
dscl . -create /Users/luser UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . -create /Users/luser RealName "Lucius Q. User"
dscl . -create /Users/luser UniqueID "1010"
dscl . -create /Users/luser PrimaryGroupID 80
dscl . -create /Users/luser NFSHomeDirectory /Users/luser
```

You can then use passwd to change the user's password, or use:

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/luser password
```

You'll have to create /Users/luser for the user's home directory and change ownership so the user can access it, and be sure that the UniqueID is in fact unique.

This line will add the user to the administrator's group:

```
dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership luser
```

Answer (score 0):

One of user-friendly ways will be to use Migration Assistant(http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4889). This GUI app will let you transfer (copy) all the account settings and file (user profile, etc) between two Macs using LAN or Thunderbolt cable.